# How is the best way to determine if a digital electric meter is working properly?

Tags: electrical-panel

I understand that if the meter says "closed" the power is on. If I shut off all the breakers, the meter still shows closed. So not sure how to test to see if the meter is working properly.

Comment: don't pay your power bill for a few months ... you'll probably see something other than `closed`

Comment: is the meter not counting up when you draw power for a time?

Comment: Think it just means the meter is connected to the system and able to pass/meter power.  If you use the power is different.  It is like you closing a light switch, but do not have a light bulb connected, the switch is still closed.

Answer (score 1):

Smart digital electrical meters have a disconnect switch that allows the power company to disconnect your power. When the switch is closed, power is going to you main breakers. If you turn off your main breakers, power still goes through the meter and to the line side of those main breakers.

A quick way to test your meter would be to turn off all your breakers except your water heater or other large user of electricity that has a nameplate stating KW. For instance, your water heater's nameplate might say "4500 Watts or 4.5 KW. Run that appliance and go check your meter. There should be a reading stating current usage, 4.5 KW. If you let the appliance run long enough, you'll see the change in the kilowatt hours display.

Comment: Agreed, may need to run some water to turn on the tank heater on. Big breakers are the same the closed is stating the contacts are closed, open= no power going beyond the meter the contacts are open.